# Opengl back object can be seen from front object

Tags: c, opengl, glut, depth-buffer

I am creating an airport scene.

I want the tower to be drawn in back of Hangar, also planes inside hangar are also visible.
If i move my eye point airplanes are also shown behind tower or hangar..
Also when i look up from below the surface objects are visible too..

Here is my code...

```
void draw()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-8.0, 0, 7);
    drawControlTower(); //grey tower
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(5, 1, 0);
    drawHangars(); // Compund to store planes
    glPopMatrix();
}

static void display()
{
    if (hiddenDepth) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
    else 
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    draw();
    
    /* Check everything OK and update screen */
    CheckGL();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

static void initGraphics (void)
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);
    /* Black background */
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

}

Comment: Did you try not turning off depth testing?

Comment: Yes it works that way but looks like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QcLB7-eD9k1HmthkNMLvfYLWMIgZfK5X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sounds like a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The issue is caused by [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). The geometry of the ground has the same depth as the geometry of the runway.

Set a depth offset by [`glPolygonOffset`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonOffset.xhtml) and enable a the depth offset before drawing the runway:

```cpp
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL); 
glPolygonOffset(-1.0f, -1.0f);
```

Disable the offsets after drawing the runway:

```cpp
glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
```

Comment: Solved it....Thanks for your great great Help...We beginners are nothing without you People :)

Comment: I have one more question...when i turn off depth test everything hides but not a rotating object which i do rotate with glRotatef...why so?

Answer (score 2):

This line turns off depth testing. Delete it:

```
glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);
```

And you should always clear the depth buffer, with:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Works great but my runway looks like this now https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QcLB7-eD9k1HmthkNMLvfYLWMIgZfK5X/view?usp=sharing